# How to display movement between groups in R plotly animation?

Tags: r, plotly

I have a dataset `sim` of individuals movements and infection status. Each day some individuals (infected or not) move from one group to another. I would like to visualise in a R plotly animation the movement of each individual. The groups should be distinguishable by their shape (`symbol` in plotly) and the infection status by the colour (red if 1, black if 0)

When only the colour argument is specified, we can see the animation works fine. However if we try to add the symbol for the group, we cannot see the points travelling from one group to another.

Thanks for the help.

```r
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

sim <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CyGei/GROUP_SIMULATION/main/sim.csv")

# Works: All points move from one group to another
good <- sim %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~ x,
          y = ~ y) %>%
  add_markers(
    frame = ~ day,
    color = ~ as.factor(infected),
    colors = c("black", "red")
  ) %>%
  animation_opts(1000, redraw = FALSE)

# Doesn't work: the points don't travel anymore
bad <- sim %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~ x,
    y = ~ y
  ) %>% 
  add_markers(frame = ~ day, 
              color = ~as.factor(infected), 
              colors = c("black", "red"),
              symbol = ~group) %>% 
  animation_opts(1000, redraw = FALSE)

# I get a warning message:
Warning message:
In p$x$data[firstFrame] <- p$x$frames[[1]]$data :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: They do move in your second plot right?

Comment: In the second plot "bad", you do not see the points travelling from one group to another.

Comment: Did you try with `animation_opts(2000, redraw = FALSE)` please?

Comment: Sorry I typoed FLASE when writing the stackoverflow question. Slowing the animation doesn't change anything. If you try my example you should spot the differences.